# Extract address Component from Maps picker address

Tags: flutter, google-maps

I have installed [Google Maps Place Picker](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_place_picker)

which return correctly maps and I can get the right address with geolocator.

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => PlacePicker(
          apiKey: APIKeys.apiKey,   // Put YOUR OWN KEY here.
          onPlacePicked: (result) { 
            print(result.address); 
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          initialPosition: HomePage.kInitialPosition,
          useCurrentLocation: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
```

now this `result` return  `return.addressComponent` which should be a list of the component of the address picked.
I need to get all of these value in a Map to push this data into firestore.
Any help?

Comment: As you'd be pushing results into firestore, you might want to take note that
apps that use Places API are bound by the Google Maps Platform [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/policies#pre-fetching,-caching,-or-storage-of-content) in which you are not allowed to pre-fetch, index, store, or cache any Content except under the limited conditions stated in the terms.

Answer (score 1):

The object `result.addressComponents` is a type of `List<AddressComponents>` where in you can iterate through using `for` loop. Here is a sample:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => PlacePicker(
         apiKey:"YOUR_API_KEY", // Put YOUR OWN KEY here.
         onPlacePicked: (result) {
              for (var i in result.addressComponents) {
                  if(i.types.first == "postal_code"){
                      print("here is the postal code ${i.longName}");
                 }
              }
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          initialPosition: _MyHomePageState.kInitialPosition,
          useCurrentLocation: true,
      ),
   ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `result.addressComponents` is a type of `List<AddressComponents>` where in you can iterate through using `for` loop. Here is a sample:

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => PlacePicker(
         apiKey:"YOUR_API_KEY", // Put YOUR OWN KEY here.
         onPlacePicked: (result) {
              for (var i in result.addressComponents) {
                  print("Short Name: " +
                         i.shortName +
                        "Long Name: " +
                         i.longName);
              }
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          initialPosition: _MyHomePageState.kInitialPosition,
          useCurrentLocation: true,
      ),
   ),
);
```

The above code will list all the `shortName` and `longName` of the place that was picked which looks something like this: [image]

Please also be mindful of the comment from @Nelson Jr that pushing this to your data base might be in violation of the Google Maps Platform Terms of Service.